# How to determine the correct value for FastCGI read, send and connect timeout?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

How should I set the value for the below directives?

I am using LEMP Stack.

```
 fastcgi_send_timeout         
 fastcgi_read_timeout
 fastcgi_connect_timeout
```

Comment: I doubt there is a hard and fast rule on this. But the facts are `fastcgi_connect_timeout ` should be lower than the other two as `fpm` is running on same machine. Next `fastcgi_send_timeout` is how much time it takes to send the request. If you don't have large uploads then it should be probably `30` secs should be good. The `fastcgi_read_timeout` timeout depends on what kind of processing your site does. I would have at least `90` secs here. But again, you workout some numbers, run the system and observe it. Then fine tune the numbers in case of issues

Comment: I am using wordpress

Comment: Then I would use https://wp-cli.org/ to generate my config. They have lot of users and you can expect the default configs to help you get started

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) is:

1. `fastcgi_connect_timeout`: time to establish connection to upstream
   (in your case is FPM)
2. `fastcgi_send_timeout`: time to upload the whole
   request until it is accepted by FPM
3. `fastcgi_read_timeout`:
   time after FPM replies accepted until the whole response is
   transmitted (downloaded) to NginX

To fine tune this:

1. `fastcgi_connect_timeout` use low values when FPM located on same
   machine, for different machine try to ping from Nginx to PHP FPM machine to determine average time to response and add a little bit seconds for safe.
2. `fastcgi_send_timeout` first you have to estimate how large the request will be, if no upload then low values is ok, when many file
   uploads with big filesize try bigger values
3. `fastcgi_read_timeout` is time to process your request in PHP and send it back to nginx. If you doing heavy lifting in PHP script, bigger values are recommended. Also if you have large response size e.g Downloading big files.

Comment: When my fpm container dies (happened once or twice, it goes dark for a couple seconds), it seems like my `fastcgi_connect_timeout` is "not" honored and nginx immediately sends the client a 502. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't wait X seconds as defined in `fastcgi_connect_timeout`?